# How do I defined undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

There's this IIFE trick to get around people that have defined `undefined` to something. It goes something like this:

```
(function (undefined) {
    // ...
})();
```

How do I become this person? Is it even possible to define `undefined` anymore?

If I open my console (FF or Chrome), it will look something like this:

```
undefined = 5  // => 5
undefined      // => undefined
```

Comment: ["*In modern browsers (JavaScript 1.8.5 / Firefox 4+), undefined is a non-configurable, non-writable property per the ECMAScript 5 specification. Even when this is not the case, avoid overriding it."*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I agree - there is no way to define it. And I will try to explain why:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window,"undefined"))
```

which, of course, prints the following:

```
Object {value: undefined, writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: false}
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) if the property `writable` is `false` then you cannot change it. Quite obvious, isn't it?

If you try to change your scope (do it inside of the function), you will be the owner of the scope and perhaps you can define the name as you like. But as far as you are on `window` scope - no way.

Comment: Verdammt. There goes my startup idea :P There should be a way to change the `writable` state.

Comment: write your own browser and voilla! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't get to assign values to undefined in modern browsers.